# Firebase custom password reset link not working

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

For the last two days I've been trying to implement a custom password reset link for my users, instead of the standard '.firebaseapp.com' domain. So, in the setup there was a short 'setup guide', with a rather small code snippet of what I am supposed to include on my web server.

Therefore I created a new directory on my root, called "users". Then I made a 'index.php' file inside that directory, that I want to handle the password reset. Lastly, I updated the code for 'index.php' according to the docs. Which was this:

```
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/3.4.0/firebase.js"></script>
<script>
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  // TODO: Implement getParameterByName()

  // Get the action to complete.
  var mode = getParameterByName('mode');
  // Get the one-time code from the query parameter.
  var actionCode = getParameterByName('oobCode'};
  // (Optional) Get the API key from the query parameter.
  var apiKey = getParameterByName('apiKey'};

  // Configure the Firebase SDK.
  // This is the minimum configuration required for the API to be used.
  var config = {
    'apiKey': apiKey  // This key could also be copied from the web
                      // initialization snippet found in the Firebase console.
  };
  var app = firebase.initializeApp(config);
  var auth = app.auth();

  // Handle the user management action.
  switch (mode) {
    case 'resetPassword':
      // Display reset password handler and UI.
      handleResetPassword(auth, actionCode);
      break;
    case 'recoverEmail':
      // Display email recovery handler and UI.
      handleRecoverEmail(auth, actionCode);
      break;
    case 'verifyEmail':
      // Display email verification handler and UI.
      handleVerifyEmail(auth, actionCode);
      break;
    default:
      // Error: invalid mode.
  }
}, false);
</script>
```

Obviously I tweaked the code, providing the valid apiKey for my app, as well as changing the two quite unnecessary errors, changing this:

```
var actionCode = getParameterByName('oobCode'};
```

to

```
var actionCode = getParameterByName('oobCode');
```

as well as:

```
var apiKey = getParameterByName('apiKey'};
```

to

```
var apiKey = getParameterByName('apiKey');
```

So when I did this, I noticed that there was no function 'getParamtersByName()'. After a Google search, I ended up with this code:

```
function getParameterByName(name) {
    name = name.replace(/[\[]/,"\\\[").replace(/[\]]/,"\\\]");
    var regexS = "[\\?&]"+name+"=([^&#]*)";
    var regex = new RegExp(regexS);
    var results = regex.exec(window.location.href);

    if(results == null)
        return "";
    else
        return decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));

}
```

So after this, I realized that the docs is significantly lacking code. According to Firebase, I also need this snippet in order to set up a password reset form:

```
function handleResetPassword(auth, actionCode) {
  var accountEmail;
  // Verify the password reset code is valid.
  auth.verifyPasswordResetCode(actionCode).then(function(email) {
    var accountEmail = email;

    // TODO: Show the reset screen with the user's email and ask the user for
    // the new password.

    // Save the new password.
    auth.confirmPasswordReset(actionCode, newPassword).then(function(resp) {
      // Password reset has been confirmed and new password updated.

      // TODO: Display a link back to the app, or sign-in the user directly
      // if the page belongs to the same domain as the app:
      // auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(accountEmail, newPassword);
    }).catch(function(error) {
      // Error occurred during confirmation. The code might have expired or the
      // password is too weak.
    });
  }).catch(function(error) {
    // Invalid or expired action code. Ask user to try to reset the password
    // again.
  });
}
```

But then again, after providing this code as well - my page is still blank. And yes, that is because there is simply no code to show a reset password screen. So my question is; how would my approach be to complete this?

Is there any projects that I can take a look at? I mean, there has to be a solution for this, as I doubt that noone is using a custom email validation link.

Help would be much appreciated.

(Please note that I have very little experience with using Firebase for web, and JavaScript is not a language that I am extremely familiar with either, but I understand it).

Comment: The instructions are pretty clear. The docs are meant to be guidelines and not github repos. They focus on the logic and the flow but leave the UI part to developers to build and customize.

Comment: @bojeil Yes, I managed to solve it all.

Comment: @askaale How did you solve this ?

Comment: @askaale can you share with as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what you should put as a firebase custom password rest link.

```
function sendEmailClick() {
    var auth = firebase.auth();
    var email, photoUrl, uid, emailVerified;
    var email;
    var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
    var emailAddress = user.email;

    auth.sendPasswordResetEmail(emailAddress).then(function() {
        // Email sent.
    }).catch(function(error) {
        // An error happened.
    });
};
```